# How do you define Exception?

Tags: php, exception

I'm used to Zend Framework, when you write your own component, you make it's own Exception file, but on per file basis, then you have such structure:

```
Zend/View/Exception.php
Zend/View/Helper/Exception.php
Zend/View/Renderer/Exception.php
```

etc.

I'm ok with, I also use Doctrine2 and Exception are "stored" in a different way

something like (in a Zend way)

and in `Zend/View/Exception.php`

```
class Exception {

public static function invalidArguement() {
   return new self('Invalid arguement was given, etc..');
}
```

I understand that the second approach is less flexible but more accurate because it throws exception according the error.

The first approach is just a way to be able to throw a Zend_View_Exception with a custom messagE.

Also, what about one Exception file per, Exception.

Like the following structure :

```
Exception/InvalidArguement.php
Exception/AuthentificationFailed.php
Exception/QuantityLimit.php
```

Is there any best practices? Any pros/cons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the best practice is to group exceptions related to their issue.

For example if you have a number of Auth exceptions, like *InvalidDetails*, *UserNotFound* put them here

- Library/Auth/Exceptions/InvalidDetails.php
- Library/Auth/Exceptions/UserNotFound.php

Each exception should be an extension of Zend_Exception ( unless you've extended it yourself )

this way you can do:

```
throw new Library_Auth_Exception_InvalidDetails("Invalid details when trying to login");
```

the benefit of using this method is you DONT need to have a message, the Exception name can cover it enough.

My assumptions here is you setup a namespace for Library called Library and everything is within there.

I tend to group everything, so a typical Auth library could be:

- Auth/Forms/Login.php
- Auth/Exception/InvalidUser.php
- Auth/Orm/Abstract.php
- Auth/Orm/Doctrine.php

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I've never worked with Zend framework but if this at all helps, I would at least make a common Exception class and all those other ones extend that rather than just make one for each.